# List values from sql search to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a search from Excel to get objects Internal ID's by External ID. In `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("J30").Value` I have External ID `f5f9a21b-9208-de11-995f-005056bb3dfa`. After search code should display Internal ID.

This one works and I am getting a message:
*There were 3 objects with the display Id of f5f9a21b-9208-de11-995f-005056bb3dfa*

How I can make this code to actually display these ID's for example starting from cell A1?

So instead of just a message:

MsgBox ("There were " & results.Count & " objects with the display Id of" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("J30").Value)

I would get the ID's in Excel? Basically I need `results.Count` not to count items but input them to Excel.

Code edited according to suggestion, but debugger is pointing to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Start").Cells(i, 1).Value = results(i)`

```
Private Sub SurroundingSub()
    Set oVault = oMFClientApp.BindToVault(szVaultName, 0, True, True)
    ' Create the condition.
    Dim condition As New SearchCondition
    Dim oScs: Set oScs = CreateObject("MFilesAPI.SearchConditions")
    Dim oVaultConnections As MFilesAPI.VaultConnections
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Set the expression.
    condition.Expression.DataStatusValueType = MFStatusType.MFStatusTypeExtID

    ' Set the condition type.
    condition.ConditionType = MFConditionType.MFConditionTypeEqual

    ' Set the value.
    ' In this case "MyExternalObjectId" is the ID of the object in the remote system.
    condition.TypedValue.SetValue MFDataType.MFDatatypeText, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("J30").Value

            'Add the condition to the collection.
            oScs.Add -1, condition

            'Search.
            Dim results 'As ObjectSearchResults
            Set results = oVault.ObjectSearchOperations.SearchForObjectsByConditions(oScs, MFSearchFlags.MFSearchFlagNone, False) ' False = SortResults

            'Output the number of items matching (should be one in each object type, at a maximum).
            'MsgBox ("There were " & results.Count & " objects with the display Id of" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("J30").Value)

            For i = 1 To results.Count
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Start").Cells(i, 1).Value = results[i]
            Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

Also () does not work:

[image]

Comment: This is not so much an Excel question than a SQL question, no? With modern Excel (2010 and later) it is much easier to use Power Query to load and process SQL data. Have you given that any thought?

Comment: This goes through our file management system called M-Files so I am not able to access sql straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a quick and direct way try this:

`For i = 1 To results.Count
    Cells(i, 1).Value = results(i - 1)
 Next i`

**Tip:** Cells(row, column)

Comment: Debugger seems to make this line red `Cells(i, 1).Value = results[i]`. This should be different `results[i]`?

Comment: You updated your code to results(i), did you try results[i]. (square brackets)

Comment: Yes, please see screenshot

Comment: You were right about the ()  brackets, using [] does not work